# Pine Script. strategy.exit for Trailing Stop and Partial Take Profit

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to have two exits on my strategy, one as a partial take profit and the other a trailing stop loss. I found some codes on the internet and I'm trying to put them together, but the trailing stop loss isn't working. It seams is something related to the order of the code. If I put the execution of the trailing stop before the partial take profit, the trailing stop works but the partial TP doesn't. I would appreciate some help. Thank you.

```
//@version=5
strategy("BASE", overlay=true, initial_capital = 1000)

//######################################################################################## TIME RANGE ######################################################################################
FromDay=input.int(defval=18,title="FromDay",minval=1,maxval=31)
FromMonth=input.int(defval=8,title="FromMonth",minval=1,maxval=12)
FromYear=input.int(defval=2021,title="FromYear",minval=2016)
dateCond = (time >= timestamp('GMT+10', FromYear,FromMonth, FromDay, 00, 00))
//######################################################################################## TIME RANGE ######################################################################################

//######################################################################################## STRATEGY ########################################################################################
// 3 rsi strategy , when all of them are overbought we sell, and vice versa

if ta.crossover(ta.ema(close,20),ta.ema(close,100)) and dateCond
    strategy.entry("BUY", strategy.long)

if ta.crossunder(ta.ema(close,20),ta.ema(close,100)) and dateCond
    strategy.entry("SELL", strategy.short)


//######################################################################################## STRATEGY ########################################################################################

//######################################################################################## TRAILING STOP AND TAKE PROFIT #################################################################
//Trailing Stop
longTrailPerc  = input.float(title='Trailing Long Loss (%)', minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=1) * 0.01
shortTrailPerc = input.float(title='Trailing Short Loss (%)', minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=1) * 0.01

longStopPrice = 0.0
shortStopPrice = 0.0

longStopPrice := if strategy.position_size > 0
    stopValue = close * (1 - longTrailPerc)
    math.max(stopValue, longStopPrice[1])
else
    0
shortStopPrice := if strategy.position_size < 0
    stopValue = close * (1 + shortTrailPerc)
    math.min(stopValue, shortStopPrice[1])
else
    999999
//################################################################### Partial Take Profit ############################
percentAsPoints(pcnt) =>
    strategy.position_size != 0 ? math.round(pcnt / 100 * strategy.position_avg_price / syminfo.mintick) : float(na)

lossPnt = percentAsPoints(2)

strategy.exit("x1", qty_percent = 50, profit = percentAsPoints(5), comment = "Loss")//, loss = lossPnt)
strategy.exit("x2", qty_percent = 25, profit = percentAsPoints(20), comment = "Loss")//, loss = lossPnt)
strategy.exit("x3", qty_percent = 25, profit = percentAsPoints(30), comment = "Loss")//, loss = lossPnt)
strategy.exit("x4", profit = percentAsPoints(4), comment = "Loss")//, loss = lossPnt)

profitPercent(price) =>
    posSign = strategy.position_size > 0 ? 1 : strategy.position_size < 0 ? -1 : 0
    (price - strategy.position_avg_price) / strategy.position_avg_price * posSign * 100

p1 = plot(profitPercent(high), style=plot.style_linebr, title = "open profit % upper bound")
p2 = plot(profitPercent(low), style=plot.style_linebr, title = "open profit % lower bound")
fill(p1, p2, color = color.red)
//####################################################################### Execution ################################
if strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.exit(id='Trailing', stop=longStopPrice, alert_message="close BTCUSDT a=usdm")
    
if strategy.position_size < 0
    strategy.exit(id='Trailing', stop=shortStopPrice, alert_message="close BTCUSDT a=usdm")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Trailing SL code looks correct

You wrote the same strategy.exit ID for

```
if strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.exit(id='Trailing Long', stop=longStopPrice, alert_message="close BTCUSDT a=usdm")
    
if strategy.position_size < 0
    strategy.exit(id='Trailing Short', stop=shortStopPrice, alert_message="close BTCUSDT a=usdm")
```

2/ With the below, the x4 exit won't be executed because x1 is closing 50% of the initial position, x2 25% of the initial position and x3 25% of the initial position.
So... there is nothing left for x4 to close

```
strategy.exit("x1", qty_percent = 50, profit = percentAsPoints(5), comment = "Loss")//, loss = lossPnt)
strategy.exit("x2", qty_percent = 25, profit = percentAsPoints(20), comment = "Loss")//, loss = lossPnt)
strategy.exit("x3", qty_percent = 25, profit = percentAsPoints(30), comment = "Loss")//, loss = lossPnt)
strategy.exit("x4", profit = percentAsPoints(4), comment = "Loss")//, loss = lossPnt)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Daveatt, I changed the exit ID, no success. Related to the x4, I know, I was just playing with the % to do some tests.